# Sychronization of periodic update and create, update and delete operation

Tags: java, rx-java2, synchronized, thread-synchronization

I use `Flowable` chain for periodic call of request (API) for tasks of users.

```
Flowable.interval(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.flatMapCompletable(_tick ->
    mUserRepository.getAllUsers()
    .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
    .flatMap(user ->
      downloadAndPersistTasks(user)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  , false, 1
);
```

Method `downloadAndPersistData` downloads current tasks of each user, remove all old tasks from database and persist downloaded tasks. Tasks of users can be changed from server side.

Problem is relatively long duration of downloading.

This case:

1. downloading of tasks - **begin**
2. insert task - API call + save to db - begin
3. insert task - API call + save to db - end
4. downloading of tasks - **end** (records without inserted task)
5. write downloaded records to db -> inserted task is **overwritten**

I need to disable downloading of data for specific user when insert API call is performed and disable function insert task when periodic update is performed.

Is there any RxJava solution or is the best choice to use native synchronization primitives of Java framework? But I don't need to skip periodic update, only delay it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that the task insertion step is done locally, along with `downloadAndPersistTasks()`.

Let's introduce a typed union: `Either<L,R>`. It has static factory methods `Either.<L>createLeft( L value )` and `Either.<R>createRight( R value )`. It also has class methods: `isLeft()`, `isRight()`, and `getLeft()`/`getRight()` to do the natural thing.

A `Subject` is used to inject the insert task step:

```
PublishSubject<InsertTask> taskInserter = PublishSubject.create();
```

Then we combine them in the following way:

```
Flowable.timer(60, SECONDS)
  .flatMap( tick -> 
      Observable.fromIterable( mUserRepository.getAllUsers() ), 1 )
  .map( t -> Either.createLeft(t) )
  .mergeWith( taskInserter.map( i -> Either.createRight( i ) ), 1 )
  .observeOn( scheduler )
  .subscribe( ti -> {
    if ( ti.isLeft() ) {
      downloadAndPersistTasks( ti.getLeft() );
    } else {
      insertTask( ti.getRight() );
    }
   );
```

The second argument to `flatMap()` ensures that only one user is processed at a time and the same for the `mergeWith()` operator. Merging the second stream ensures that only one operation is ever performed at a time, and the `observeOn()` operator puts all operations on to the same thread, so there will be no contention.

If you need greater parallelism, or finer grained control, you may need to introduce an observable per user.

Comment: Where did you find operators fromIterable and mergeWith with 2 parameters?

Comment: `.flatMap()` takes a parameter which is the number of parallel subscriptions. I made a mistake with `mergeWith()` as the `merge()` operator does take a parallelism limit if you provide a list of observables.

Comment: I have method for peridic update mentioned above and create, update and delete methods in different classes. Is possible use Java sync primitives for solution of problem? When I call insert(update, delete) than disable (wait) emmiting of item for specific user and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, you can use Java synchronization primitives. You would need to perform the synchronization from your periodic update code, and your create, update and delete methods in the other classes.